# How do I determine the web application uri from IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

At the end of the installation process of a ASP.NET web application, I would like to open up the browser to the application. Is there a way to determine what the URI is from IIS? Maybe something in Microsoft.Web.Administration?

Comment: Do you mean something like clicking on "Browse Application" in the right hand column under Manage Application?

Comment: I would assume you'd be setting up the binding when creating the IIS site -- how do you not know the URI?

Comment: @Jason Yes, just like that except something that can be done programmatically.

Comment: @George I'm installing into an existing site so I don't know what the bindings are for sure.